Nan values are generating while interpolating data over 800 hpa using wrf python but working in 300,500
i am working on netcdf file and interpolating data for geopotential height 850hpa , 700hpa, 500hpa and 3oohpa
    height =getvar(ncfile, 'z', timeidx=i)
    pressure=getvar(ncfile,'pressure',timeidx=i)
    temp=interplevel(height,pressure,850)

while inspecting data,height and pressure are completely numeric value, and while interpolating data for 500 and 300 , it is working well
what might be the reason behind this and solution for this

The 850hPa level corresponds to about 1,450masl: your NaNs are probably low mountains. 500hPa is about 5,500masl, above most terrain worldwide

yes, actually this region is himalyan region where value is NaN, i got the reason, but what should i do ,leave it blank, this will create a white region at nan value , which i think is not good appraoch

It all depends on your intended use. If there is no 850hPa atmospheric level then leaving it blank seems like a sensible approach
